# Change grid line colour/contrast in MATLAB polarplot

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, figure, axes

I'm struggling to figure out how to change the grid line colours in a polar plot in MATLAB. I tried to manually change some axes properties that could possibly do that, but couldn't observe any changes. Just to be clear: It's not about the axes themselves, but the grid lines (inner circles) that are drawn for orientations should be black (or have a better contrast) since this light grey is suboptimal for e.g. a presentation shown with a projector.

[image]

How can I change the colour of the grid itself?

Comment: There seems to be an option within the axes called `GridColor`, which you could set to `[0 0 0]`, i.e. black. Something like `ax = plot(1:10); ax.GridColor = [0, 0, 0]`. (I can't test this, as my MATLAB is old). Otherwise, you could manually draw a circle on each of the tick-radii and colour that by hand (which is the only way to set the grid to *different* colours as far as I can find)

Comment: The way to do it differs considerably whether you are using `polar()` (old version) or `polarplot()` to generate the graph. Please indicate which function you are using.

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for noticing. I added a note in my answer

Comment: @Adriaan I actually tried that, but nothing in the plot changed. Probably didn't do it quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`polarplot`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) (note that [`polar`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) is not recommended), you need to set the `GridColor` and `GridAlpha` [properties of the axes](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html). These properties control color and transparency, respectively. For pure, non-transparent black use

```
set(gca, 'GridColor', [0 0 0], 'GridAlpha', 1)
```

Comment: I actually was using `polarscatter`, didn't think this would matter. However, this line worked for me just fine! Thank you very much.

Comment: @MD98 I see. I was thinking that black grid lines would perhaps look too strong compared to a plotted curve (`polarplot`), but with markers (`polarscatter`) they make more sense